# Find the general solution to the equation $f'(z)+2zf=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the equation $f'(z)+2zf=0$

---

Since $f=u+iv$ is differentiable at $z$ so $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x$,Looking at the equation we should find $f(z)$ such that $u_x(x,y)=-2zu(x,y)$ and$v_x(x,y)=-2zv(x,y)$, so $$\frac{u_{x}\left(x,y\right)}{u\left(x,y\right)}=-2z\implies \ln\left|u\left(x,y\right)\right|=-2zx+\alpha(y)$$
$$\implies u\left(x,y\right)=e^{-2zx}e^{ \alpha(y)}=e^{-2zx}c_1(y)$$

And
$$\frac{v_{x}\left(x,y\right)}{v\left(x,y\right)}=-2z\implies \ln\left|v\left(x,y\right)\right|=-2zx+\beta(y)$$
$$\implies v\left(x,y\right)=e^{-2zx}e^{ \beta(y)}=e^{-2zx}c_2(y)$$

On the other hand $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, so $$-2ze^{-2zx}c_1(y)=e^{-2zx}c'_2(y)$$
$$e^{-2zx}c'_1(y)=-2ze^{-2zx}c_2(y)$$
Which shows that

$$4z^{2}e^{-2zx}c_{1}\left(y\right)-e^{-2zx}c_{1}^{''}\left(y\right)=0$$

Now how to find $c_{1}\left(y\right)$?

Comment: Your first approach is wrong in its execution. In separating into real and imaginary parts, you should get $u_x=-2Re(zf)=-2(xu-yv)$. The second equation will also be coupled.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too complicated. Here is simple solution: The derivative of $e^{z^{2}}f(z)$ is $e^{z^{2}} (f'(z)+2zf(z))$ which is given to be $0$. Asssuming that your domain is an open connected set we get $f(z)=ce^{z^{2}}$ for some constant $c$.